# docker nginx php-fpm file_get_contents not working

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I'm running a composition of two docker images (nginx and php-fpm). Both are working completely fine and I can open my example website but I get one error when using `file_get_contents` in PHP:

```php
Warning: file_get_contents(/data/nav.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/localhost/partials/header.php on line 3
```

My nginx points to `/var/www/localhost` and the `data` folder is in the root. Relative URI's like `data/nav.json` in my index.php are working as well as full URL's to other websites.

Full source code is available here: https://github.com/muuvmuuv/webserver

I also opened an issue on on GitHub from Docker PHP: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/836

I would like to know if this is caused by nginx or php-fpm and why absolute urls are not working.

Comment: When you say "the data folder is in the root", do you mean the root of the filesystem, or the root of the website? Sorry if this is a stupid question but you say `data/nav.json` works, as though this is at the root of the website.

Comment: @contrebis sry, I mean the root of the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this part from your code is wrong

```
$url = "/data/nav.json";
```

you're looking for a file in the wrong directory.

This change worked for me

```
$url = __DIR__ . "/../data/nav.json";
```

Comment: This is not a wrong directory. The dir exists in `/` and when I access images via `/img/img.png` it's working, so this should too. I can also access `/data/nav.json` directly in the browser.

Comment: I think we're talking about two different things.
If you want to load nav.json from the local file system as it is in the code, the folder you are using is incorrect because the nav.json file is in the `/../ data /` file from the header.php perspective.
If you want to retrieve nav.json from the url address as you say that the file is available from the browser, then you must enter the url address in this case on nginx container (maybe `nginx / data / nav.json`), so it is a communication between two containers.

Comment: Okay so `/var/www/localhost/data/nav.json` seems to work but why? I mean, I tell nginx that the root is localhost/ so how can I tell PHP to do act like the same, so I can just `/data/nav.json` or is this just the wrong way of thinking?

Comment: `/var/www/localhost/data/nav.json ` is basically the same as `__DIR__ . "/../data/nav.json"` (from `header.php`)
You need to determine if you want to load a file from a local filesystem or from another container.
According to the documentation
[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) input is `filename` Name of the file to read.
Therefore I think that setting the root dir for file_get_contents is not possible.

Comment: Makes sense but I bind the localhost dir to both container not only the nginx container (otherwise it would not work) that is why I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago and I solve it with relative path:

```
file_get_contents(getcwd() . '/data/something.json');
```